# MySQL запрос: получить строки, посчитав строки другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с заказами orders (id, name, limit_per_day)
Есть таблица с отчётами по заказам orders_reports (id, order_id, date)

Нужно получить все строки из таблицы orders, где значение поля limit_per_day не превышает количества строк в таблице orders_reports для заданного order_id и date.

Пишу подобным образом, но это явно не работает:

```
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders 
WHERE orders.limit_per_day>=(SELECT count(1) 
                             FROM orders_reports 
                             WHERE orders_reports.order_id=orders.id 
                               AND orders_reports.date>='2022-02-14')
```

Как правильно?

Comment: Ну если некая заданная дата - то должно быть равенство, как бы...

Comment: ну сути не меняет это) всё равно запрос работает некорректно в текущем виде.

Comment: Выложите пример исходных данных в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, критерий (значение даты) и требуемый результат для именно этих данных.